# why does "[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]"cause memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I am using x-code 6.3 instruments to analyze my application, but I don't understand why this line cause memory leak:

```
+ (NSString*)IDFV
{
    NSUUID* device_id = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];// !100%
    return [device_id UUIDString];
}
```

I wanted to post a picture but not enough reputations.

iI chose instruments-leaks-call tree,and select 'invert call tree' and 'hide system libraries',then I got one of the leak codes shows above, can someone help,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't leaking memory *as such*

`UIDevice currentDevice` returns a singleton - that is, each subsequent call to `currentDevice` will return a reference to the same object instance.

This singleton instance is allocated on the first call to `currentDevice` and this object will remain allocated until your app exits.

This shows up as a "leak" (and technically is a leak because the object can never be released) but this is by design and nothing to be concerned about.